# Fmx TStringGrid row color

Tags: delphi, background-color, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin, stringgrid

I have a problem in Delphi 10.1 in a multi-device application (on Windows).
I have a `StringGrid` (connected to a db) and I can change background color of row, but the problem is there is a "padding" (in grey/silver) between cells.

In `onformCreate` I define:

```
stringgrid1.DefaultDrawing := False;
```

This is my code:

```
procedure Tlist_form.StringGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Canvas: TCanvas; const Column: TColumn; const Bounds: TRectF;
  const Row: Integer; const Value: TValue; const State: TGridDrawStates);
   var aRowColor: TBrush;
begin
  aRowColor := Tbrush.Create(TBrushKind.Solid,TAlphaColors.Alpha);


  if (stringgrid1.Cells[7,row]='1') then 
        aRowColor.Color := TAlphaColors.Green
    else
      aRowColor.Color := TAlphaColors.Red;

    Canvas.FillRect(Bounds, 0, 0, [], 1, aRowColor);
    Column.DefaultDrawCell(Canvas, Bounds, Row, Value, State);

  aRowColor.free;

end;
```

In Delphi 6 I've never had this problem, and I don't know how to fix-it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution 1 (at design time):**

For each `StringColumn` locate the `Padding` property and change all values from 3 to 0.

**Solution 2 (at run time):**

Add a `TRectF` to local vars. Assign it the value of `Bounds` and `Inlfate()` it. The modified `OnDrawColumnCell()` looks like this:

```
procedure TForm30.StringGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Canvas: TCanvas; const Column: TColumn; const Bounds: TRectF;
  const Row: Integer; const Value: TValue; const State: TGridDrawStates);
var
  aRowColor: TBrush;
  aNewRectF: TRectF;
begin
  aRowColor := TBrush.Create(TBrushKind.Solid, TAlphaColors.Alpha);

  if (StringGrid1.Cells[7, Row] = '1') then
    aRowColor.Color := TAlphaColors.Green
  else
    aRowColor.Color := TAlphaColors.Red;

  aNewRectF := Bounds;
  aNewRectF.Inflate(3, 3);
  Canvas.FillRect(aNewRectF, 0, 0, [], 1, aRowColor);
  Column.DefaultDrawCell(Canvas, Bounds, Row, Value, State);

  aRowColor.free;
end;
```

The grid looks like this with both solutions:

[image]

To also remove the lines between the cells, untick `ColLines` and `RowLines` in the grids `Options`.

Comment: it says " E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical"
on " InflateRect(aNewRectF, 3, 3);"

Comment: Hmmm... It compiled fine for me. Doublecheck that you declared `aNewRectF` as a `TRectF` (ending in 'F') and also try writing the constants specifically as floats, as 3.0

Comment: yep are  aNewRectF and TRectF, tried changing value, using float, using const but i have alway same error (and cursor goes just after first parameter of  InflateRect(aNewRectF,3,3)

Comment: When you place the mouse cursor on `InflateRect` what does the hintwindow show as the fully qualified name and parameters

Comment: parameters are TRect@,integer,integer

Comment: I asked what the fully qualified name is. For me it shows `Types.InflateRect()` and additionally "declared in System.Types" For me the parameters are `TRectF@, Single, Single`

Comment: The only way I can reprodce the prolem you claim is by declaring erroneously `aNewRectF: TRect;` as the variable. The correct declaration is `aNewRectF: TRectF;`

Comment: for me it was `windows.InflateRect()`, then i changed line in `system.Types.InflateRect(aNewRectF, 3,3);`
and now it works! 
Thankyou Tom.

Comment: Another option was to use: aNewRectF.Inflate(3, 3);

Comment: Yes @roumen that is correct! I chaged my answer accordingly, thanks for the suggestion.